# Is there any way to use OS users in a self-hosted file-sharing platform?

Tags: server, file-sharing, file-management, owncloud

I use ownCloud to self-hosted the servers and I want to use OS users to log in to the ownCloud web UI so everyone who has access to the servers will have access to the ownCloud web UI without creating a new user in Owncloud.

 If it's impossible, is there any alternative to ownCloud which can do that?

 Thank you.

Comment: owncloud and nextcloud have different authentication backends. Also one that authorizes against system accounts.